# Show image after upload

Tags: asp.net, asyncfileupload

I used this article for show image after upload without refresh page.
[Display image after upload without page refresh or postback using ASP.Net AsyncFileUpload Control](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-image-after-upload-without-page-refresh-or-postback-using-ASP.Net-AsyncFileUpload-Control.aspx)

I customize the `FileUploadComplete` because I want to create name for uploaded files:

```
protected void FileUploadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(AsyncFileUpload1.FileName);
    filename = Uploader.CreateNameForFile(filename);
    AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(this.UploadFolderPath) + filename);
    Session["image"] = filename;
}
```

After I change the code, Image doesn't shown after upload.
what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

you have to have javascript for this scenario:

from code behind

url = location of saved image

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType(), "image", "top.$get(""" & _img.ClientID & """).src = '" & url & "';", True)
```

[Display image after upload without page refresh or postback using ASP.Net AsyncFileUpload Control](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-image-after-upload-without-page-refresh-or-postback-using-ASP.Net-AsyncFileUpload-Control.aspx) 
shows you how to do it from client side